# Groovy - How to regex a string having substring QA?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In the below code:

```
        print env.gitlabSourceBranch // prints develop

        if ((env.gitlabSourceBranch !=~ ".*QA.*").matches()) {

            error('Aborting Build - not a QA branch')
        }
```

flow should proceed only if `env.gitlabSourceBranch` has substring `QA` in it, otherwise exit with error

---

if `env.gitlabSourceBranch` value is `develop`, then *if condition* is trying to compare with regex `.*QA.*`, but I get below error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.matches() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

---

How to resolve this error?  Shall I use `if(!(env.gitlabSourceBranch ==~ ".*QA.*")){}`?

Comment: Yes: `if(!(env.gitlabSourceBranch ==~ ".*QA.*"))` or `if(!(env.gitlabSourceBranch =~ ".*QA.*").matches())`. As a side note, it's more simply (and perhaps more efficiently) done with `if(!env.gitlabSourceBranch.contains('QA'))`